# Read Unknown-sized Array in Ajax from XML

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

How can I read and sign XML data (array of different sizes) using jQuery?

AJAX to read line node from XML and store in javascript array, in XML array size is not constant.

My Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "sites.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('msg').each(function() {
                var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                i = 0;
                tic = new Array();
                $(this).find('desc').each(function() {
                    tic.push($(this).find('line').text());
                    alert(tic[i]);
                    i++;
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and XML File (Demo)

```
<msgs>
    <msg>
        <title>ABC</title>
        <desc>
            <line>test 1</line>
            <line>test 2</line>
            <line>test 2</line>
        </desc>
        <time>5</time>
    </msg>
</msgs>
```

Can Someone help me out please

Comment: Can you add more info on how you want to sign it ? perhaps an example of the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read in all of the `line` elements into an array change

```
tic.push($(this).find('line').text());
```

to

```
$(this).find('line').each(function() {
    tic.push($(this).text());
})
```

This will process each `line` element and add it to your array and then place your array initialisation at the top `var tic = [];` ... so complete success function would look like this :

```
var tic = [];
$(xml).find('msg').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).find('title').text();
    $(this).find('line').each(function() {
        tic.push($(this).text());
    });
});​
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/6gcCH/)

Comment: $MAnseUK i have  dataType: "script", how can i read value from this file , script file contains Array